# Analysis of covariance in R

Tags: r, ancova

1. How do you carry out analysis of covariance using R?
2. How do you interpret the results?
3. A practical example will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a [detailed presentation](http://www3.imperial.ac.uk/pls/portallive/docs/1/1171922.PDF)

Comment: Lamentably, in that document Crawley perpetuates the myth that ANCOVA can be applied to scenarios when the covariate is correlated with an IV, even when this explicitly violates an assumption of ANCOVA.

Comment: thanks for the document. i will take a close look at it.

Comment: ancova makes no such assumption. your statement is tantamount to saying multiple regression is only valid with uncorrelated predictors, which is not true.

Comment: "No such assumption" refers to what?

Comment: Would you be able to summarize this presentation here?

Comment: I think he/she was referring to the comment by Mike Lawrence. I don't know a lot about ANCOVA, but I didn't think there was any such assumption, because I thought ANCOVA was a special case of multiple regression.

Comment: @mark Thanks.  That indicates this reply is really a comment and shows us where to relocate it.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very clear presentation from a biologist:

[R in Ecology & Evolution: Comparing two regression slopes by means of an ANCOVA](http://r-eco-evo.blogspot.com/2011/08/comparing-two-regression-slopes-by.html)